# How to use SELECT2 or similar for filter LOOKUP field

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, ootb

I have two lists:

`Customers`
`Customers_Documents`

The customer list is large -> **>10.000 items**. When i bind the customer via a lookup field to the Customer_Documents list in general it works, but it is not very user friendly cause of the large amount of items.

Is there a way to use something like SELECT2 or similar to filter/search for items within lookup column?

I need a way without programming, cause i am only able to use OOTB functions like JS, SPDesigner, WebParts etc.

Comment: Using OOTB functions, you're out of luck. Sorry.

Comment: Hm, no luck with SPDesigner, Script Parts, etc.?

Comment: Sure, you could inject some JavaScript (using JSLink, content editor WebPart or SPDesigner) and modify the visualization of the lookup. It wouln't be OOTB, though.

Comment: Ah ok, but if this is possible that would be fine for me. But is this possible? I would also update my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id*='LookupField']").select2({
            ajax: {
                url: function(params){
                    return "**yourSharepointSiteAddres**/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('**yourLookupList**')/items?$filter=substringof('"+params.term+"',**yourLookfielYouWantFilter**)";
                }
                ,dataType:'json'
                ,processResults: function (data) {
                    var f='{"results": ['
                        ,counter=0;
                    data.value.forEach(function(ele) {
                        var $f="";
                        if(counter==0)$f="";else $f=",";

                        f+=$f+'{"id":'+ele.ID+',"text":"'+ele.**yourLookfielYouWantFilter**+'"}';
                        counter++;
                    }, this);
                    f+="]}";
                    f=$.parseJSON(f);
                    return f;
                }/// End processResults
            }/// End Ajax request
        });/// End select 2 function
    });//// End Document ready function
</script>
```

Remove all ** from your code

you can visit this link

https://www.vlieshout.net/tag/select2/